# How do you write to the linux keyboard buffer in c?

Tags: c, linux, bash, keyboard, command-line-interface

I want my program to do something similar to when you press the up arrow in bash, and it "types" your last command into the keyboard buffer for you.

I am writing a CLI flashcard program, and I want the user to be able to make a small change to a long word using the arrow keys instead of having to type it all out.

I cannot find any concrete explanation or example anywhere on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to write to the keyboard buffer. What you want is a readline like functionality.

Check the following link: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

or (far simpler)

https://github.com/antirez/linenoise